# DaVinci Resolve doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, symbolic-link, davinci-resolve

DaVinci Resolve doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
mkadmi@poor-thinkpad-e470:~$sudo dpkg --install davinci-resolve_16.2.1-1_amd64.deb
(Reading the database... 249466 files and directories already installed).
Preparing to unpack davinci-resolve_16.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking davinci-resolve (16.2.1-1) from (16.2.1-1) ...
rmdir: Cannot remove '/usr/lib64': Folder is not empty
Setting up davinci-resolve (16.2.1-1) ...
ln: Cannot create symbolic link '/usr/lib64/libDaVinciPanelAPI.so': File exists
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) .
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
```